# cron job can not access Windows files after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: permissions, backup, cron, duplicity

cron starts a duplicity job to do an incremental backup of my system, desktop.
A partition is NTFS, /media/OS/Program Files ...
Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 (from 16.04) the job cries Can not access file /media/OS/Program Files ... possibly locked.

The permissions for the NTFS directories and files can not be set.

So what can I do (if I do not want to downgrade to 16.04)?

Comment: from a terminal can you verify that path is visable/mounted  ?   just to simplify the issue

Comment: Yes, ls -alF show all the files`~$ ll /media/OS/Program\ Files*
/media/OS/Program Files:
total 201
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak  12288 Oct  4 19:38 ./
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak  12288 Oct 25 21:35 ../
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak      0 Jun 16 10:24 Artifex Software/
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak   4096 Apr 18  2016 Common Files/
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak      0 Mar 31  2015 Dell/
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak      0 Aug 19  2011 Dell Inc/
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak      0 Aug 19  2011 dell stage/
drwx------ 1 tpollak tpollak   4096 Aug 31 18:12 Dell Support Center/`
...

Comment: duplicity is 0.7.06